# Importing a shared object as a module fails

Tags: python, python-import

I want to create a package with the following structure:

```
file.py
package_name/
package_name/__init__.py
package_name/module_a.py
package_name/module_b.so
```

`module_a` uses `module_b` and works well. But if I try to load the package `package_name` or the containing module `module_a` from `file.py`, an error occurs, that no `module_b` can be found.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` contains `.` which is the current working directory. If you call `module_a` directly, it's the directory it is in, if you call `file.py` it's `file.py`'s directory and the library can not be found there. You have several options to changes that.

- Change your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the environment. That can be done in your .bashrc, in a shell scrip calling your python files, by prefixing the call with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/your/path` or by modifying `os.environ` in Python.
- you can also symlink the library to the other folder.
- you can install the library to a system-wide library folder.